# Objective-C: window undeclared

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

It will be a noob question, but i'm getting crazy with this. I've read a tons of topics but i think i am missing something main.

I`ve created new cocoa app project, did not change anything, just add next code to main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSView *superview = [window contentView]; 
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 100); 
    NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [button setTitle:@"Click me!"]; 
    [superview addSubview:button]; 
    [button release];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

During compiling xcode tells me that window undeclared. I understand that instead of window should be name of my NSWindow object, but i don`t understand which name has NSWindow which automatically created in MainMenu.xib file.

Please help, i`m almost ready to broke the wall with my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point no window has even been created yet. The code generated by Xcode gives you `window` in your projects application delegate, so add your code to `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in `YourProjectAppDelegate.m` instead.
I recommend to start with some [introductory material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources) like [Hillegass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) where such things should be covered in detail.

Comment: Thank you. I`m not a developer, its just a hobby, besides my english skills not so perfect and sometimes it is difficult to understand some special developer things and there are only two books about objective-c in russian.

Comment: @Alex: I guess that sounded harsher than it was intended. As your english sounds fine i somehow assumed lazyness; sorry if i misinterpreted.